# Formatting of Excel cells in R: combination of thousand separators und two signs after decimal comma

Tags: r, openxlsx

i am formatting cells of created Excel document with R-package `openxlsx`.

The required format of cells in Excel output-file is: "10.000,02" - i.e. with:

- point as thousand separator;
- comma as decimal separator;
- two signs after comma.

If i apply the code:

```
cell_style <- createStyle(numFmt = "#.##0,00")
```

the number in Excel file seems as "10000,02111" - only with comma as decimal separator, but without thousand separators and with more than two signs after comma.

If the following code is applied:

```
cell_style <- createStyle(numFmt = "COMMA")
```

the number in Excel file is "10.000" - with point as thousand separator (despite that function containts "comma"...) but without decimal ceparator and signs after it.

After application the code:

```
cell_style <- createStyle(numFmt = "NUMBER")
```

the number in Excel file seems as "10000,02" - with comma as decimal separator and two signs after, but without point as thousand separator.

What should i apply to receive "10.000,02"?

Comment: Try with `createStyle(numFmt = "#,##0.00")`. As far as I get it, via `numFmt` you only specify whether you want a decimal or thousands separator, but which symbol is used depends on the settings in Excel, e.g. in my case the decimal separator in Excel is set to "," and the thousands separator to ".". Hence, applying the mentioned style results in numbers formatted with a "," as the decimal mark and a "." as the grouping mark.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the following approach, which is based on the RDCOMClient R package. With the RDCOMClient R package, you can define the "DecimalSeparator" and the "ThousandsSeparator" used in the Excel file. This approach only works on Windows.

```
library(RDCOMClient)

path_Excel_File <- "D:/empty_Excel_File.xlsx"

xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
xlApp[["UseSystemSeparators"]] <- FALSE 
xlApp[["DecimalSeparator"]] <- ","
xlApp[["ThousandsSeparator"]] <- "."
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_Excel_File)
Sheets <- xlWbk$Sheets()

vector_Val <- c(10000.02)
vector_Format <- c("#.##0,00")
nb_Val <- length(vector_Val)

for(i in 1 : nb_Val)
{
  cell_Obj <- Sheets[[1]]$Cells(1, i)
  cell_Obj[["Value"]] <- vector_Val[i]
  cell_Obj[["NumberFormat"]] <- vector_Format[i]
}
```